# Google Analytics Report Api start-time fail

Tags: php, google-analytics

i made simple PHP code to show uniquePageViews for my website. The main code was for 7days, but i want to make it lifetime and when i made start-date: "2017-10-5" it start shows me errors. But [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#startDate) that i can place date in that type.

Work variant:

```
try { 
        $result = $service->data_ga->get( $GA_VIEW_ID, '100daysAgo', 'today','ga:uniquePageviews'); 
        $count = $result->totalsForAllResults['ga:uniquePageviews']; 
        echo $count; 
    } catch(Exception $e) { 
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

Fail variant:

```
try { 
        $result = $service->data_ga->get( $GA_VIEW_ID, '2017-10-5', 'today','ga:uniquePageviews'); 
        $count = $result->totalsForAllResults['ga:uniquePageviews']; 
        echo $count; 
    } catch(Exception $e) { 
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation you linked](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#startDate) (Emphasis mine) :

> All Analytics data requests must specify a date range. If you do not include start-date and end-date parameters in the request, the server returns an error. Date values can be for a specific date by **using the pattern YYYY-MM-DD** or relative by using today, yesterday, or the NdaysAgo pattern. Values must match [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-**[0-9]{2}**|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo).

Which means your day must be displayed with two digits. Try `2017-10-05` as your start date.